# wide to long in pandas while aligning columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example:

```
pd.DataFrame({'time' : [1,2,3],
              'X1-Price': [10,12,11],
              'X1-Quantity' : [2,3,4],
              'X2-Price': [3,4,2],
              'X2-Quantity' : [1,1,1]})

Out[92]: 
   time  X1-Price  X1-Quantity  X2-Price  X2-Quantity
0     1        10            2         3            1
1     2        12            3         4            1
2     3        11            4         2            1
```

I am trying to reshape this wide dataframe into a long format. The difficulty is that I want to break down the variables by type (identified by the X1, X2 variables) while keeping price and quantity aligned on the same rows. That is, the desired output is the following

```
Out[93]: 
   time type  quantity  price
0     1   X1         2     10
1     2   X1         3     12
2     3   X1         4     11
3     1   X2         1      3
4     2   X2         1      4
5     3   X2         1      2
```

I am not sure how to do this. I tried the `pd.wide_to_long()` function but it does not work correctly.

```
pd.wide_to_long(b, i = 'time', j = 'value', stubnames = ['X'])
Out[95]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [X1-Price, X2-Price, X2-Quantity, X1-Quantity, X]
Index: []
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) requires a specific order. First invert the chunks around the `-`, then change some of the default parameters:

```
# alternative:
# tmp.columns = df.columns.str.split('-').str[::-1].str.join('-')
tmp = df.rename(columns=lambda s: '-'.join(s.split('-')[::-1]))

out = (pd.wide_to_long(tmp, i='time', j='type', 
                       stubnames=['Quantity', 'Price'],
                       sep='-', suffix=r'X\d+')
         .reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
   time  type  Quantity  Price
0     1    X1         2     10
1     2    X1         3     12
2     3    X1         4     11
3     1    X2         1      3
4     2    X2         1      4
5     3    X2         1      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is alternative with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and `MultiIndex` by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
out = (df.set_index('time')
         .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.str.split('-', expand=True), axis=1))
         .stack(0)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'level_1':'type'}))
print (out)
   time type  Price  Quantity
0     1   X1     10         2
1     1   X2      3         1
2     2   X1     12         3
3     2   X2      4         1
4     3   X1     11         4
5     3   X2      2         1
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot_longer), and depending on the data size can be faster than `pd.wide_to_long`:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.pivot_longer(index='time',names_to = ('type','.value'), names_sep='-')
   time type  Price  Quantity
0     1   X1     10         2
1     2   X1     12         3
2     3   X1     11         4
3     1   X2      3         1
4     2   X2      4         1
5     3   X2      2         1
```

For the code above, the `.value` determines which part of the column remains as a header; for complex use cases, you can use `names_pattern` instead of `names_sep` (`names_pattern` relies on a regular expression)